# Microsoft access query returning incorrect result when called from Excel using ADO

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ado

i have a query saved in microsoft access 2010 which when run from within access returns the expected result (no records found).

However, when i use an ADO connection from excel (a select query), i get some rows back which is confusing because i already have criteria in the query that excludes the results which are returned.

I have tried a comibination of things including changing the cursorlocation property to aduseclient, changing the cursortype to static and then also tried changint it to keyset as shown below:

TRIAL 1

```
Set objRst3 = New ADODB.Recordset
objRst3.Open strSql, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset
```

TRIAL 2

```
Set objRst3 = New ADODB.Recordset
objRst3.Open strSql, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic
```

i have also tried including my criteria in the select statement sent from excel and also excluding the criteria and instead placing it in the query designer within microsoft access.

Im not using the JET driver to connect to access, the connection string im using 
is

```
GetAccessConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & path & ";"
```

However, im still getting the strange result. How can i get round this please

**EDIT**

The structure of my query is as follows. The filter criteria that is not being picked up from excel is the line 'AS MAIN **WHERE STATUS <> "CLPd"'** :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ..
FROM 
        (
          SELECT DISTINCT ... STATUS
            FROM ( 
              SELECT distinct .. FROM ... AS OD 
              LEFT JOIN ((select ...FROM ..) as ST) on (OD.id = st.id) and      (od.ord = st.ord)
            )
        ) AS MAIN WHERE STATUS <> "CLPd"
LEFT JOIN 
        (
           SELECT DISTINCT ....
            FROM tbl1
            INNER JOIN tbl2 on tbl1.id = tbl2.id
            WHERE tbl2.col1 = "Y" and tbl1.col2 = "Y"
            ORDER BY tbl1.id  
        ) AS ITEMCONFIG on MAIN.itemcode = ITEMCONFIG.itemcode
WHERE
        (
        MAIN.CUSTMR not Like "OTHER*" and MAIN.DATE < DATE()
        )
ORDER BY MAIN.DATE
```

Comment: Currentproject.connection wont exist in Excel, you need to create an ADO Connection

Comment: @Nathan_Sav thanks for your response. But i dont think the problem is connecting to the database. The "currentproject.connection" is pseudocode . my connection object is called conn so wanted something that made some sense here. im able to connect and retrieve data. its this particular query that has an issue.

Comment: Ok, with out seeing the data in, data out and the SQL, I cant really advise, its like me asking you why my data isn't as expected.